# Sql query when one of tables could have more results

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I'm trying to do a query to show images attached to a "room" table but one room may have more images than another. I have 3 tables :

- "answer" table - this holds all form info stored from the app.
- "room" table - this has a "form id"(the id of the answer table) and some room details
- "roomimage" table - this has a "room" id and a url for the images, so there could be 10 pictured for one room and 5 for another, for the same form.

My question is, is it possible to get all these details in one query? I know the fact that the last table can have multiple columns may be an issue? I tried the below :

```
select 
    answer.id, room.name, room.description, roomimage.image_url 
from 
    answer
inner join 
    room on room.form_id = answer.id
inner join 
    roomimage on roomimage.room_id = room.id
where 
    answer.id = 3
```

but if a form has a room that has 2 images, it is returning 2 rows, I want it to be 1 row with dynamic columns like on the attachment (bottom image)

[image: results]

Comment: You'll want to look into the UNPIVOT command.

Comment: Yes, It's possible, you have to use `DYNAMIC PIVOT`. Also which one dbms are you using? *MySQL* or *SQL-Server*?

Comment: Better to show all urls in single column comma separated  by using GRUOP BY Clause

Comment: See,if number of rows return is very less in then don't bother to unpivot in sql itself,you can pivot it in front end too.Then I like @SunilPachlangia ideal too.It all depend how you hv to use it.Then off course You can use PIVOT.Say,number of images can never be more than 5 (Business Rule) then no need of DYNAMIC PIVOT.here you can follow [@@Dege] advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it by limiting the number of maximum results you want to get:

```
select answer.id,room.name,room.description,
    (select roomimage1.image_url FROM roomimage AS roomimage1 on roomimage1.room_id = room.id LIMIT 0, 1) AS image_url_1,
    (select roomimage2.image_url FROM roomimage AS roomimage2 on roomimage2.room_id = room.id LIMIT 1, 1) AS image_url_2,
    (select roomimage3.image_url FROM roomimage AS roomimage3 on roomimage3.room_id = room.id LIMIT 2, 1) AS image_url_3,
    (select roomimage4.image_url FROM roomimage AS roomimage4 on roomimage4.room_id = room.id LIMIT 3, 1) AS image_url_4,
    (select roomimage5.image_url FROM roomimage AS roomimage5 on roomimage5.room_id = room.id LIMIT 4, 1) AS image_url_5
from answer
inner join room on room.form_id = answer.id
where answer.id = 3
```

It's not pretty but by doing this you get up to 5 results (NULL when not present)

**NB:**
This was the answer in full SQL, if you can access the data with a scripting language you can process manually the results of your query.

Comment: Surely this violates the [Zero-One-Infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) rule. What if there are six images? What if you need a hundred?

Comment: Yeah, you're definitely right, but I don't know if there are limits imposed on the number of images. This is dirty but it's fast and works (with image numbers limitations) ;)

Comment: Yeah we can only have up to 10 images a room using the app so this is ok for now. Thanks